# How to use setMultiChoiceItems() with a Custom AlertDialog that uses an efficiency arrayadapter?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I am writing a music player that uses a custom Adapter extending BaseAdapter (efficiency adapter) that I want to display in an `AlertDialog` using `setAdapter()` where the user can either click on one of the songs to switch to that position in the playlist OR check songs to remove from the playlist. I tried using a custom click listener so that a user could just long click to remove the item from the list but the `listview` just doesn't work right... it was removing the wrong items (the ones at the end) even though the `ArrayList` contained the correct playlist items... (when I removed the item from the `ArrayList`, I passed it to the adapter which called `notifyDataSetChanged`... but that just didn't work as I mentioned. There is definitely a bug in the `AlertDialog ListView`... because there is no reason for it to have popped off the results from the end rather than the correct item.

So... the next method I would like to try is to use the `setMultiChoiceItems()` method of the `AlertDialog`... but it appears that it doesn't work with a custom adapter... only simple arrays. Will I have to subclass `AlertDialog` and `Override` the `setMultiChoiceItems()` method or is there a way I can make it work with an `ArrayAdapter`?

Basically, I can't figure out how to even iterate the list that the `AlertDialog` creates or whether it even passes that view somehow. In addition, I don't think I can even listen to clicks on `checkboxes` if I add those to the row. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: Asking questions here is like magic... I answered my own question... this is how I did it. I added a hint to each `checkbox` which is the position of the item in the `ArrayList`. Then I used `OnCheckedChangeListener` to capture the selections. When you set a hint it adds text to the `checkbox`... since the background of the `AlertDialog` is white (even for clicked items?) I just set the hint text color to transparent.

```
holder.check.setHintTextColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
holder.check.setHint(String.valueOf(position));
holder.check.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
            boolean isChecked) {
        int position = Integer.parseInt((String) buttonView.getHint());
        Log.v("onCheckedChanged", "Checked: "+isChecked+" returned: "+position+" which should be "+getItem(position).name);                         
    }

});
```

Comment: your question is answered by yourself on your own question. Try to copy/paste the text and use the answer mechanism properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Refer [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5067641/how-uncheck-items-in-alertdialog-setmultichoiceitems) and [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5652777/clickable-rows-on-custom-arrayadapter)

then 
Pass a reference to byte[] in `setMultiChoiceItems().`

```
final boolean[] booleans = {false, true, false, true, false, false, false};
```

Then check the value of `booleans` inside `setPositiveButton().`

If you need to pass this `AlertDialog` around, then extend `AlertDialog` and have create a field boolean as described in 1.